# Why doesn't breakpoint run on odata Web api application?

Tags: soap, odata, asp.net-web-api, restful-authentication, restful-url

i created Odata service in side of the web api. i put a break point on GetFavoriteStation. but it is not working. 
mydomain:127.0.0.1

i called this URL : mydomain/odata/2013-06/X(guid’23C868DC-07FE-4AC4-B399-D4E76EDE9F0C’)
but it is not working.  it returns to me error. ERROR: **The resource cannot be found.**

```
  [AllowAnonymous]
public class XController : EntitySetController<X, Guid>
{

    [Queryable]
    public X GetX([FromODataUri]Guid id)
    {
        X x= null;
```

Look App_Start files

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
namespace Y.Z
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/2013-06/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that these are suspicious:

1. The entity set X is not defined in the builder
2. Maybe should replace config.Routes.MapODataRoute("ODataRoute", "odata/2013-06", model); with config.Routes.MapODataRoute("ODataRoute", "odata-2013-06/*", model);
3. If it is an odata service there is no need to do this:

   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                   name: "DefaultApi",
                   routeTemplate: "api/2013-06/{controller}/{id}",
                   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
               );